# Fuzzy search complexity in lucene

Tags: lucene, fuzzy-search

I am using lucene 4.10.4.

Can anyone explain me how fuzzy search works? How much search time increases when compared to normal search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Lucene 4, fuzzy search was implemented more efficiently, by usage of [Fast string correction with Levenshtein automata paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10032-002-0082-8?LI=true)

> To make a very long story short this paper shows how to recognize the
>   set of all words V in an index where the Levenshtein distance between
>   V and the query does not exceed a distance d, which is exactly what
>   one wants with Fuzzy Search.

Of course it still will be slower, than just straight lookup, that you will do for a concrete term, however it's not a performance killer anymore.